# NUC suggestion please

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I plan to get a NUC to run ROS1 now and ROS2 few months later. Are all Intel NUC compatible with ROS1 and ROS2? Any good product suggestion? Are there any specific CPU instruction sets (e.g. perhaps AVX?) that ROS can take advantage of? NUC come with different GPU. Which iGPU are compatible with the ROS1 and ROS2? Is any one model of GPU better than the other? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348576/nuc-suggestion-please/) by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no particularly special requirements. Pick whichever CPU you like / meets your needs for compute.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-06**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-04-06**:
Can you mark this as correct to get off unanswered questions queue?

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-06**:
OK. Where do I mark as correct? Also, which iGPU is recommended?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-04-06**:
Its the little checkmark next to the vote arrows.

Pick the GPU that meets your processing specs for your application. There's no generally  right or wrong answer. There's nothing special about ROS disabling you from writing GPU code in any particular architecture.

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-06**:
Thanks. Too bad we cannot add an Nvidia GPU to the NUC.